# Javascript Syntax Explanation - Conditional?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Can someone please explain what the following javascript statement is doing?

```
var default_hide = {"grid": true };
```

It looks like some sort of conditional statement similar to a ternary statement?

Comment: It's called an "object literal".

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defining an object with a `grid` property that is set to `true` which is being assigned to `default_hide`.

In that context, the braces are defining an `Object`.

Comment: Thanks - after hitting post the proverbial "light bulb" turned on and I realised what it was doing.  Will accept your answer as soon as I am able.  Thanks for you super quick response.

Answer (score 0):

It's declaring a object named "default_hide", with one property named "grid" and its corresponding value "true".

After this declaration, you can do: document.write(default_hide.grid);